# Delete row with a Mysql Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

need to do trigger after Inserting on a table called jos_jquarks_quizzes, I need to create a course name which will have the same name as the quizz name , but its own id,

Tables

```
jos_jquarks_quizzes 

id     title     description     course_id 

jos_jquarks_users_training   
id     quiz_id     user_id     agree
```

So far My Trigger looks like this but has an error

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `db_dhruniversity`$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `db_dhruniversity`.`ai_delete_course`
AFTER DELETE ON `jos_jquarks_quizzes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
DELETE FROM jos_jquarks_courses
WHERE (quiz_id = new.id); 
END$$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your where clause change new.id to old.id

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `db_dhruniversity`$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `db_dhruniversity`.`ai_delete_course`
AFTER DELETE ON `jos_jquarks_quizzes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
DELETE FROM jos_jquarks_courses
WHERE (quiz_id = old.id); 
END$$
```

Comment: Thanks I wish I could learn more about triggers can you suggest a good tutorial>?