# I have error "#1363 - There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger "

Tags: sql, mysql, database, triggers, mysql-error

I have `book` and `store_order` tables.

I want to make trigger(but it contain error):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
    
CREATE TRIGGER t1 
BEFORE DELETE ON store_order
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    
    UPDATE book SET number = number + NEW.quantity WHERE ISBN = NEW.ISBN;
    
END
$$
    
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you want to access the data of the row which is to be deleted, you should use :old variable. Since there is no new row to be inserted (as it is a delete row trigger) you cannot use :new here.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: I do that before delete and i want to update in other table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete row with a Mysql Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209188/delete-row-with-a-mysql-trigger)

Comment: I only want to correct "update line" which problem on it :)

Comment: I wander what is the problem in question to make it down vote ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER t2 AFTER delete 
    ON library.store_order
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        update library.book 
        set library.book.number = (library.book.number + OLD.quantity)
        where library.book.ISBN = OLD.ISBN;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use OLD instead of NEW when you want to get the deleted object.

for an example of my case. I'm getting the id of the newly added role by calling

> NEW.id

and getting the same field's value while deleting by calling

> OLD.id

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_role
AFTER INSERT ON role FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `sync_mapping`
 (`operation_type`, `table_name`, `oid`, `end_point`) 
  VALUES
 ('insert', 'role', NEW.id, 'new/role');
END $$


 DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_role
  AFTER DELETE ON role FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `sync_mapping` (`operation_type`, `table_name`, `oid`, `end_point`)        VALUES
  ('delete', 'role', OLD.id, 'delete/role');
END $$
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we are deleting the data
USE

> OLD. instead of NEW.

> CREATE TRIGGER user_history_delete AFTER DELETE ON user FOR EACH ROW
> INSERT INTO user_history(action , name )
> VALUES ("Delete" , OLD.name );

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) says below:

> `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

So, `NEW.col_name` only works for `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
   -- ↑ Here
...
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON test FOR EACH ROW
   -- ↑ Here
...
```